# Divide in SQL with a where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to divide where Salesman is `Yes` and Product is `Pen` ***over*** the total amount of sales (in my case is 8) and get the total percentage.

```
select * from mytable   

Sale_Number      Date            Salesman_Used           Product

 1            01/01/2014             No                    Pen
 2            01/02/2014             No                    Pen
 3            01/03/2014             Yes                   Pen
 4            01/04/2014             Yes                   Pencil
 5            01/05/2014             Yes                   Pen
 6            01/06/2014             Yes                   Pencil  
 7            01/07/2014             No                    Pencil
 8            01/08/2014             No                    Pencil
```

I am stuck on the missing piece:

```
select concat(100 * count(missing this piece) / count(Sale_Number), '%') 
as "Salesman Sales for Pens"
from mytable
where Salesman_Used = 'Yes' 
and Product = 'Pen'
```

The problem with my attempt is that the `where clause` affects the `Sale_Number` as well.. How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [`filter`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-expressions.html) clause for an aggregates:

> If FILTER is specified, then only the input rows for which the filter_clause evaluates to true are fed to the aggregate function; other rows are discarded.

So:

```
select concat(100 * count(*) filter (where Salesman_Used = 'Yes' and Product = 'Pen') / count(Sale_Number), '%') 
as "Salesman Sales for Pens"
from mytable
```

Comment: Thanks Abelisto, a small request please. The answer is vividly twice, the Salesman was used and with `Yes`. What if I want to divide the 2 by the (Number of times Yes appears in the whole table) 100% ? Let us presume the `Yes` appeared six times so 2 / 6 * 100% = 33.3% This is requested.

Comment: @JakeWagner Yes, it will be yet another `count(*) filter (where ...)` in the expression. Just `select count(*), count(*) filter (<condition1>), count(*) filter (<condition2>), <etc> from mytable;` and then combine values in the desired expression.

Comment: @JakeWagner BTW `filter` could be inefficient on the large amount of data because it ignoring indexes. In this case you can simply replace `count(*) filter (where <condition>)` by subqueries like `(select count(*) from mytable where <condition>)`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a subquery to get the overall count of sales entries:

```
select concat(100 * count(*) / (select count(*) from mytable), '%') 
as "Salesman Sales for Pens"
from mytable
where Salesman_Used = 'Yes' 
and Product = 'Pen'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select concat(100 * count(missing this piece) / count(select Sale_Number from mytable), '%') 
as "Salesman Sales for Pens"
from mytable
where Salesman_Used = 'Yes' 
and Product = 'Pen'
```

Answer (score 1):

I have never used Postgresql but maybe this works:

```
select concat(100 * (select count(*) from mytable) / count(Sale_Number), '%') 
as "Salesman Sales for Pens"
from mytable
where Salesman_Used = 'Yes' 
and Product = 'Pen'
```